# Laravel 5.0 Event Ignored

Tags: php, laravel, events, handler

I'm using Laravel 5.0 (on an older project) and the event-handler is being ignored.

> Any idea if I'm forgetting something?

#### This is the App\Providers\EventServiceProvider

```
protected $listen = [
    SupplierCreated::class => [
        NotifySupplierCreated::class,
    ]
];
```

#### This is the App\Events\SupplierCreated

```
class SupplierCreated extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    public $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd('Event'); // This dd() is working! The other one isn't
    }

}
```

#### This is the App\Handlers\Events\NotifySupplierCreated

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\SupplierCreated;

class NotifySupplierCreated {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

     /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SupplierCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SupplierCreated $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }

}
```

#### And this is my Client calling code

```
event(new SupplierCreated($supplier));
```

Comment: try with full namespace, i.e `SupplierCreated::class => [App\Handlers\Events\ NotifySupplierCreated ]`

Comment: Same result. Not working, thank you for your time

Comment: What happens when you remove the dd('here') in the App\Events\SupplierCreated and just leave the dd($event) in the handler. Is it giving an error or what are you seeing?

Comment: Have you tried this:
`public function __construct($supplier)
{
   dd($supplier); 
}`
Inside your event class

Comment: @Anderscc it's giving no result, just skipping the event. (thank you for your time)

Comment: Added an answer with that I think you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing something in your **App\Providers\EventServiceProvider**

You need to add the following

```
 <?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

use App\Events\SupplierWasCreated;
use App\Handlers\Events\NotifySupplierCreated;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = 
        SupplierWasCreated::class => [
            NotifySupplierCreated::class,
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        //
    }
}
```

As everything else looks like it should be working fine.

I've implemented this event using your code. Only thing that was missing for me was the above in the EventServiceProvider.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SupplierWasCreated extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $supplier;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($supplier) 
    {
        $this->supplier = $supplier
    }
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Then your handler

```
<?php

namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\SupplierWasCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NotifySupplierCreated {

    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

     /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  SupplierCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(SupplierWasCreated $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }

}
```

Comment: :( damnit. both are included in the exact way you propose. This is weird! Thanks for your time

Comment: Nope I don't understand. I'll try some different methods of doing this. maybe without the event() helper

Comment: If you copy the above into your files. It should work straight away. It'll definitely hit the handler. The only thing you'd need to change is the filename for SupplierCreated to SupplierWasCreated.